# Angular 6 custom Input component

Tags: angular

I have created a custom `input` component in Angular 6. This input component can be either of type `text` or `number`. If it's a number, I need to validate for `min` and `max` values.

The validation works, but the value of the input does not get updated on the second time. The model updates tho.

The component looks like that:

```html
<input [type]="type" [min]="min" [max]="max" (keyup)="change($event.target.value)" [value]="value">
```

That is ma **change** event on `keypress`:

```js
change(value: any): void {
    if (this.max) {
      if (value > this.max) {
        this.value = this.max;
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
        return;
      }
    }

    if (this.min) {
      if (value < this.min) {
        this.value = this.min;
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
        return;
      }
    }

    this.value = value;
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
  }
```

That is my complete `InputComponent`

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-custom-input',
    templateUrl: 'input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

    @Input() value: any = null;
    @Input() type = 'text';
    @Input() min: number;
    @Input() max: number;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    change(value: any): void {
      if (this.max) {
        if (value > this.max) {
          this.value = this.max;
          this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
          return;
        }
      }

      if (this.min) {
        if (value < this.min) {
          this.value = this.min;
          this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
          return;
        }
      }

      this.value = value;
      this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    }
}
```

Why is the input value not being updated? The model updates properly. If I debug the code I see that `this.value` is the value expected, but in the DOM it's not.

[image]

The image above shows the value in red circle should also be in the input value. As you can see, the model is correct, but the input value is not updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `[value]` by a `ngModel` :

```html
<input [type]="type" [min]="min" [max]="max" (keyup)="change($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tkvcc?embed=1&file=src/app/input.component.html)